# Method called before a scheduled UILocalNotification is fired?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I've scheduled a local notification and want to fetch data just before the notification is going to be fired, however I can't find a relevant method.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: exactly... What data you want to fetch? Notification data? Core Data?

Comment: ah sorry, I want to access a web API and display some of the response data in the notification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not how notifications work.

Notifications rely on your app being closed or in the background. If your app is closed, there is no method that is called because, well, your app isn't running! Notifications don't launch your app, which is the only way you can detect that a notification has been fired.

If your app is in the background or active, your app delegate receives a `-application:didReceiveLocalNotification:` call. This happens *after* the notification is fired, and you cannot modify the contents of the notification or prevent the notification from showing at this point.

It seems like what you're trying to do isn't really suited to local notifications. To access a web API, it might be better looking into making a simple polling script on a web server that sends remote notifications. You can also look into Background App Refresh, but again, your app is not guaranteed to be active when every notification is sent, and some users disable this feature.